# What's the best way to recursively traverse a BinaryTree in Java without void methods?

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree, preorder

Learning about binary Trees through a MOOC right now and I want to recursively traverse the tree and add data to a List but the assignment i'm working on doesn't want the method types to be changed. I know with a void method I could just do something like:

```
public static void preorder(TreeNode<T> root) {
    List<T> listOfData = new ArrayList<>();

    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }
 
   
    listOfData.add(root.getData());
 
    // Traverse the left subtree
    preorder(root.getLeft());
 
    // Traverse the right subtree
    preorder(root.right);
}
```

but right now my method is

```
public List<T> preorder(TreeNode<T> root) {
    List<T> listOfData = new ArrayList<>();

    if (root != null) {
        listOfData.add(root.getData());
        preorder(root.getLeft());
        preorder(root.getRight());
    }

     return listOfData;
}
```

doesn't appear that the list is updating per stack call beyond the initial return.

Comment: Neither works. Pass the list as a parameter and create it outside the recursion. Nothing to do with void/non-void whatsoever.

Comment: you must add the result of (resursivel) calling `preorder` to the result list (see method `addAll()`)

Comment: By the way, Asking a "What is the best way" to do something increased the risk of a question being closed for seeking an opinion. For a question like this, it's better to ask "How to" do something.

Comment: You must either pass the accumulator in as a parameter or return the data as the return type. If you cannot modify the parameters or the return type of the method, the only hope would be to have the accumulator be an instance variable or field of a singleton, which would be rather ugly.

Comment: What is the purpose of the function? To *collect* data in a list? Are you sure that is what you are being asked to do? Where is the list that is going to get the result, so the initial caller has access to it?

Comment: @user85421 That's not sufficient. As written, the list can never escape this method so it is all pointless.

Comment: "Without void methods" is an arbitrary and toxic constraint. You're best to ignore it and get the job done.

Comment: @user207421 How "*the list can never escape this method*"? From the question: "right now my method is `... return listOfData; }` " !?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know with a void method I could just do something like: [...]

The `void` function you presented doesn't do the job: the caller has no access to the local array list. Each call of this function creates a local list with at most one member, and when it returns that list is no longer accessible and flagged for garbage collection.

You're asking to get the function working *without* `void` return type (as stated in the title), but it is true that in your attempt you're only returning a list with again at most one member.

The problem is that your code ignores the lists that are returned by the recursive calls, yet that is the only information they give you. If you ignore that, you might as well not make those calls at all. They do work for nothing.

Here is the correction of your attempt:

```
public List<T> preorder(TreeNode<T> root) {
    List<T> listOfData = new ArrayList<>();
    if (root != null) {
        listOfData.add(root.getData());
        listOfData.addAll(preorder(root.getLeft() ));
        listOfData.addAll(preorder(root.getRight()));
    }
    return listOfData;
}
```

Comment: True but there's a lot of unnecessary adding to lists going on here, and indeed a lot of unnecessary lists.

Comment: Yes, that is the consequence of sticking with the given function signature (in combination with the requirement that it should use recursion).